# Maven, NPanday, C#, Hudson and NUnit

Tags: c#, asp.net, nunit, continuous-integration, hudson

This is more a development process discussion than an out and out question.

What do you all think should about the above tools being used together within a development team. would these tools fit together well and what about configuration (hard|simple).

I work for a company that needs to overhaul its development practices and I wanted to get some advice to go along with my research.

I feel we need to start making use of dependency management and couple these dependencies with stringent NUnit tests, also make use of Maven (along with the NPanday extension). Then kick off hudson' continuous integration.

So over to you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using and managing maven environment for couple of years now.

So yes if you are looking for better binary version management capability , with automated build and unit test , moving to maven would be great Idea. You can Achive Build and release management using below tools

However I am using maestro(Continuum) instead of Hudson. You can achieve better Build and release management capability by combining below tools.

1. NPanday : VS maven plug-in for building .NET projects
2. NUnit   : Maven executes unit test with the build.
3. SVN     : Source code version management
4. Maestro : A Build server technology to build projects directly from Subversion. http://www.maestrodev.com/documentation/maestro-2.3.5/continuum/index.html
5. Archiva : Binary management capabiility http://archiva.apache.org/

Comment: I'm using it with Jenkins + Nexus. Works fine, too.